# Best data-structure to save a word to a corresponding number?

Tags: python-2.7, data-structures

I'm pretty new to python and just need some advice. I'm basically making a python reddit tool that will help me find the top comments, their score, and save them so they can be sorted by highest score at a later time.

Initially I was going to save them to a dictionary with a 'score:comment' format but was told this was not ideal. Any suggestions for the best route to go in this situation?

Comment: Without further information, a list of (score, comment) tuples seems reasonable. To save this list, CSV would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on sorting it, just use an array. Arrays just make it so much simpler when it comes to sorting.

Choosing a data structure mainly lies in your goals for the application. Would you like quick indexing and look up times? Use an array. Is your input size unknown, and search times are not as important? Use a linked list. Are search times incredibly important? Use a hash table